Splitting a string with a delimitator in R using mutate and str_split
I am working in R. I am wanting to split a string up e.g. "laura-smith-X12344G" into FirstName, LastName and nino. There is always the "-" deliminator.
df_current <- data.frame(data_current = c("laura-smith-X12344G", "james-breen-Y12345G", "ben-thomas-G333334"))

df_want <- data.frame(data_current = c("laura-smith-X12344G", "james-breen-Y12345G", "ben-thomas-G333334"), 
                      FirstName = c("laura",  "james", "ben"),
                      LastName = c("smith",  "breen", "thomas"),
                      nino = c("X12344G", "Y12345G", "G333334"))

data_want:



data_current
FirstName
LastName
nino




laura-smith-X12344G
laura
smith
Y12345G


james-breen-Y12345G
james
breen
Y12345G


ben-thomas-G333334
ben
thomas
G333334



I would like a solution to fit into dplyr mutate.

Check out separate_wider_delim

df_current %>% tidyr::separate_wider_delim(data_current, delim = '-', names = c("FirstName", "LastName", "nino"))

df_want <- df_current %>%
           mutate(FirstName = stringr::str_split(data_current, "-") %>% map_chr(., 1)) %>%
           mutate(LastName = stringr::str_split(data_current, "-") %>% map_chr(., 2)) %>%
           mutate(nino = stringr::str_split(data_current, "-") %>% map_chr(., 3))


